# How to run/develop laravel + vue.js (laravue) app properly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-artisan

before i start, i need to say that i'm aware that this question is a beginner's one.

I've found this dashboard combination of Laravel and Vue.js that i wanted to play with, to then start developing a real web application. [laravue](https://github.com/tuandm/laravue)

There's just a single question that is confusing me: while testing it on xampp with the commands "npm run watch" and "php artisan serve" i see myself obliged to npm run the project, every time i make a file change.

So what is the right way to check all the changes i make? By just refreshing the browser window.

Comment: I use Laravue, really helpful and well structured (Vue file structure can get messy..)
 'npm run watch'  will do the auto build whenever you save anything.. just keep it running

Comment: i let it run, but i all i get is a message about "compiling successfully" and then i can't find my app anywhere in localhost.

Comment: You need to run php artisan serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run watch` automatically builds your assets and then watch any save on the concerned files. Whenever a save happens, `npm run watch` rebuilds everything, but you won't be aware on your web browser except by refreshing.

**P.S:** Sometimes `npm run watch` does not work well, then use `npm run watch-poll` instead

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#running-mix

Comment: So i ran watch-poll and got the "build successful" message. Then i remembered to open a second cmd window and ran "php artisan serve" and it worked fine!  I just don't think this is the right way, or is it?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all the responses.

I've solved the problem by running "npm run watch" and "php artisan serve" on two separated command-line windows.

Was totally unaware of that and it's part of the learning curve. 
Thank you, this is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. `npm run watch` or `npm run watch-poll` will automatically rebuild your assets but don't apply to the browser without manual refresh. Meaning you have to reload browser after compiling done.
2. Hot Module Replacement(HMR - or Hot Reloading) works same as `npm run watch` and apply changes to browser automatically, so you don't have to reload browser to see the changes.
3. Following this [document](https://doc.laravue.dev/guide/essentials/hot-reload.html#with-built-in-development-server), HRM works well with the fresh installation (latest code on master) as my test.

`npm run hot` result:

```
➜  npm run hot
> laravue@0.11.0 hot [src]
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from [src]/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
```

`php artisan serve` result:

```
➜  php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

And browser:

[image]